# DATE FORMAT in jsqlparser 0.8.6

Tags: date, format

```
SELECT CAST('8888-12-31' AS DATE FORMAT 'yyyy-mm-dd') AS DOB,
FROM EMPLOYEES;
```

While I try to parse the above SQL, its throwing an exception. I verified its not taking date format.

Comment: I fail to see the question, are you asking how you should modify the query to not include `DATE FORMAT`?

Answer (score 0):

This type of date cast followed by a format specifiation is not (yet) supported by JSqlParser. 
You could file an issue at github for an improvement.

Maybe it is an typo but after DOB there should be no comma.